# Append similar keys from a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
x={'a':"a",'b':"b"}
```

and

```
y={'a':"c",'b':"d"}
```

I want this:

```
z={'a':"ac",'b':"bd"}
```

How do I do this with Python?

Comment: Explicitly. There are several obvious ways to implement `x + y` for `dict`s, including your desired result, but none of them are obviously better than the others, so Python does not provide any of them.

Comment: Are `x` and `y` guaranteed to have the same set of keys?

Comment: `{k:"".join(v) for v in zip(x.values(), y.values()) for k in y}`?

Answer (score 5):

```
z = { k : x.get(k, '') + y.get(k, '') for k in x.keys() | y.keys() }
```

This is a dictionary expression (`{...}`), mapping every element `k` from the set combination (`|`) of both `x.keys()` and `y.keys()` to the concatenation of the respective values (or concatenation of a present value and empty string, as specified as the default argument of `get`).

Comment: The OP left this unspecified, but this approach omits keys from `y` that aren't present in `x`.

Comment: And if they don't? Perhaps use `.get(k, '')`?

Comment: @roganjosh great idea. Updated

Comment: excuse me?  what's awful about that question?

Comment: @BrocolliRob no need to beat around the bush: Your question is bad because it doesn't show any attempt of your own, just asks for a solution for a problem that one can definitely solve with a little thought "manually", but maybe less elegant. I see that there might be a few problems when some keys are in `y` that aren't in `x`, but you could at least have shown what you've tried to give the people here something to start. The way you asked was plain lazy.

Comment: Oh please, how high and mighty of you.  How do you know what I've done to try and solve this?  Am I supposed to put up the last 40 minutes of syntax errors and complaints from the interpreter to somehow prove to you that I've done my homework?  I know how to Google and I know I don't know what I don't know. Python has many subtleties that one may not run into, and this instance is certainly one of them. My question was succinct and to the point, and your attitude that since I didn't properly satisfy your need to see what I have tried before coming here and asking for help is just plain rude.

Comment: And thank you @YevhenKuzmovych for the answer without any judgment from the pulpit of the religion of SO.

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of `x` and then enumerate over all keys of `y` and append their values to the values in the copy. Use `z.get(key, '')` to catch the case of missing values.

```
z = x.copy()
for key in y.keys():
   z[key] = z.get(key, '') + y[key]
```

You can generalize this to having more than two dicts

```
z = {}
more_than_two = [x, y]
for each in more_than_two:
    for key in each.keys():
        z[key] = z.get(key, '') + each[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

This program takes an arbitrary number of dictionaries and sums them. It does something useful even if there are unique keys in some of your dicts:

```
def do_sum(*args):
    result = dict()
    for d in args:
        for k, v in d.items():
            result.setdefault(k, "")
            result[k] = result.get(k, "") + v
    return result

x={'a':"a",'b':"b"}
y={'a':"c",'b':"d"}
z = do_sum(x, y)
assert z=={'a':"ac",'b':"bd"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import copy

z = copy.copy(x)  # We use copy to avoid changing x in the following for loop

for k in z.keys():
    z[k] += y[k]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> z
{'a': 'ac', 'b': 'bd'}
```

Comment: Deep copy isn't really necessary.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I agree. `copy.copy()` would be enough!

Comment: Or just `x.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections

x = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
y = {'a': 'c', 'b': 'd'}

z = collections.defaultdict(str)

for d in (x, y):
    for k, v in d.items():
        z[k] += v

dict(z)
# {'b': 'bd', 'a': 'ac'}
```